# Angular routing error and right way to do it?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angular, angular-cli

I've been learning angular to use with my ruby on rails application and am having some problems with the routing

this is my app.routing file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//Layouts
import { FullLayoutComponent } from './layouts/full-layout.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full', },

  {
    path: '', component: FullLayoutComponent, data: { title: 'Página Inicial' },
    children:
    [{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
    { path: 'organizations', loadChildren: './organizations/organizations.module#OrganizationsModule' },     
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

this is the organizations.module file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

//Routing
import { OrganizationsRoutingModule } from './organizations-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    OrganizationsRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class OrganizationsModule{ }
```

and this is the organizations-routing.module file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { OrganizationsComponent } from './organizations.component';
import { OrganizationFormComponent } from './organization-form/organization-form.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: OrganizationsComponent,
    data: { title: 'Organizações' },
    children: [

      {
        path: 'new', component: OrganizationFormComponent,
        data: { title: 'Cadastrar nova Organização' }
      },
      {
        path: ':id', component: OrganizationFormComponent,
        data: { title: 'Mostrar Organização' }
      },
      {
        path: ':id/edit', component: OrganizationFormComponent,
        data: { title: 'Editar Organização' }
      },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes), CommonModule, FormsModule],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations:[OrganizationsComponent, OrganizationFormComponent]
})
export class OrganizationsRoutingModule { }
```

doing it this way, the /organizations path works, but /organizations/new don't, I get this error on the console:
[image: error]

Other way that I tried is to put everything on app.routing, resulting in something like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//Layouts
import { FullLayoutComponent } from './layouts/full-layout.component';
import { OrganizationsComponent } from './organizations/organizations.component';
import { OrganizationFormComponent } from './organizations/organization-form/organization-form.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full', },

  {
    path: '', component: FullLayoutComponent, data: { title: 'Página Inicial' },
    children:
    [{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },    
      {
        path: 'organizations', pathMatch: 'full', component: OrganizationsComponent,
        data: { title: 'Organizações' },
      },
      {
        path: 'organizations/new', component: OrganizationFormComponent,
        data: { title: 'Cadastrar nova Organização' }
      },
      {
        path: 'organizations/:id', component: OrganizationFormComponent,
        data: { title: 'Mostrar Organização' }
      },
      {
        path: 'organizations/:id/edit', component: OrganizationFormComponent,
        data: { title: 'Editar Organização' }
      },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

this works, but as far as I have seen, it isn't the best way to do it.

How should I build my routes?

thanks!

Comment: what problems are you facing. update screenshots to post

Comment: added the error that I get in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of mistakes on your logic

First of all, Why would you redirect `''` to `'dashboard'` and then have `'dashboard'` be a child of `''` ??

Also you should never use `pathMatch: 'full'` when the `path: ''` has children

You should do the following in my opinion:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: FullLayoutComponent, data: { title: 'Página Inicial' },
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard' },
        { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
        { path: 'organizations', redirectTo: '/organizations' },     
      ]
    },
];
```

**organizations-routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'organizations', component: OrganizationsComponent,
    data: { title: 'Organizações' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'new', component: OrganizationFormComponent,
        data: { title: 'Cadastrar nova Organização' }
      },
      {
        path: ':id', component: OrganizationFormComponent,
        data: { title: 'Mostrar Organização' }
      },
      {
        path: ':id/edit', component: OrganizationFormComponent,
        data: { title: 'Editar Organização' }
      },
    ]
  },
];
```